# Rule of 5 when move code is the same as copy code?

Tags: c++, move-semantics

Say my class only has one member, an `int`.  There's no benefit to "moving" this int instead of copying it.  Do I therefore need a move constructor and a move assignment operator that both simply do the same thing as their copy cousins?

Comment: you don't need any one of the five unless your class dynamically allocate memory

Comment: Fair enough, but let's say I'd like users to be able to construct objects based on existing objects and to assign objects.  Even though they're obviously not mandatory, I WANT a copy constructor and copy assignment operator.  I have nothing against people doing move construction and move assignment, but if I don't supply explicit methods for these, will the copy versions simply be called?

Comment: @SwissFrank there is implicitly generated copy and move constructor and assignment operators   , if your class doesn't do anything to disable them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your class does nothing special with the copy members or the destructor, the best thing to do is to declare none of them:

```
class A
{
    int i_;
public:
    // Special members
    A() : i_{0} {}

    // Other constructors
    explicit A(int i) : i_{i} {}

    // ...
};
```

This gives your class compiler-generated copy and move members (and destructor) that are the same as those for `int` itself.

If your class does something special for the destructor or either of the copy members, and you want the compiler generated behavior for the move members, then you must `= default` them.  Otherwise, you will have no move members, which is probably exactly what you want (copying from rvalues uses the copy members).

```
class A
{
    int i_;
public:
    // Special members
    A() : i_{0} {}
    A(const& A a);                 // do something special
    A(A&&) = default;              // just copy the int
    A& operator=(A&&) = default;   // just copy the int

    // Other constructors
    explicit A(int i) : i_{i} {}

    // ...
};
```

Note that it would be highly unusual for your class to behave differently for copying from an lvalue and copying from an rvalue as described with the code above.  I can't immediately come up with a motivating use case for such code.

If you want to be able to copy rvalues of your class, but with no special "move" treatment (just use copy), then the typical formulation is:

```
class A
{
    int i_;
public:
    // Special members
    A() : i_{0} {}
    A(const& A a);             // do something special for lvalues and rvalues
    A& operator=(const& A a);  // do something special for lvalues and rvalues

    // Other constructors
    explicit A(int i) : i_{i} {}

    // ...
};
```

Now clients can still "move" `A`, but the moves just copy according to `A`'s copy members.

Comment: many thanks Howard.  In your example you have `int i_`.  Say I have a C type: `typedef int Foo`.  does your answer still completely hold?  I'd get an autogenerated copy ctor, move ctor, copy assign op, and move assign op?

Comment: Yes.  Type aliases such as `Foo` make no difference whatsoever.